# Problems w/ recognizing inputs to do different tasks

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is that when a the program asks if you would like to add another student it would say "Would you like to add another student `Y/N`?"
And if `Y` is inputted then it would let you add another and if you input `N` it would take you back to the main menu of my program. So I set `Y=1` and `N=0` I'm just trying to figure out how the program would read the `Y` and know what to do.

```
public class TestStudent {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {  
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in );
            BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader( isr );


        String check, tempString, tempString2, setName, getName, setScore, getScore;
        int tempInt, tempInt2, y, n;
        boolean quit = false;
        y=1;
        n=0;
        Student s1, s2, s3;
        s1 = new Student();
        s2 = new Student();
        s3 = new Student();

        do
        {
            System.out.println("A - Add student, D - Delete student, F - Find student, H - Help, S - Scores, X - Exit");
            check = stdin.readLine().toLowerCase();
            switch (check)
            {

                case "a":                
                    System.out.println("Enter the student's name");
                    tempString = stdin.readLine();
                    s1.setName(tempString);
                    System.out.println("Would you like to add another student Y/N?");
                    tempString = stdin.readLine();
                    if (y=1) {
                        System.out.println("Enter the student's name");
                        tempString = stdin.readLine();
                    }
                    s2.setName(check);
                    s3.setName(check);
                break;
```

Comment: `if (y=1) {` is using the assignment operator `=`. Dunno if it's a typo.

Comment: Hey nickkbmod, just 2 questions. Why are you converting the code to lower case? And is any specific reason you dont use a nice wrapper for System.in, such as Scanner?

Comment: `y` is always `1` (despite of the typo)

Comment: And `y=1` is not a boolean expression so `if (y=1)` will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

First you will want to add `toLowerCase` to your `tempString` assignment.

```
tempString = stdin.readLine().toLowerCase();
if (tempString.equals("y")) {
```

This will check the string they gave you against y, your version just updated (`=` means assignment) a variable you weren't using.

Comment: should use `.equals()` to compare Strings

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Syntax between C# and Java always makes me forget to check the tag ><.

Comment: @Guvante you actually shouldn't use `==` in Java as well :)